# Spring: Security-context doesn't save my password

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am writing the rest app with basic authentication. It works fine but every time after restart it generates new user password.
My Security-context.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security

           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config='true'>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:http-basic />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="user" password="password1" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Why it doesn't take password="password1"?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "it generates new user password" ? Where do you see this? Also, please post the debug log for when the authentication request is submitted.

Comment: In console when my app starts something like "Using default security password: c80fe464-e7e8-4t1e-8cea-123f26d702c3"

Comment: If you search for that phrase "Using default security password", it seems to be a Sprint Boot feature of some kind which creates a default "user". There are various issues related to it [on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2567). Make sure you are using the latest versions of everything and try using a different username which won't conflict with the default.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Checked and tried, nothing helps (((((

Comment: Spring Boot, by default, creates a default user with a generated password. Basically your xml is doing nothing at all and can (or should) be removed. If you want to specify users yourself, configure Spring Security as specified in the Spring Boot reference guide.

Comment: The default password can easily be over written within your application.properties.

Comment: @ccit-spence Could you tell me, please, what should I write in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the user and password within the `application.properties` file as follows.

```
security.user.name=user # Default user name.
security.user.password= # Password for the default user name. A random password is logged on startup by default.
```

This is directly from the Spring Boot Properties docs [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Unless you have a good reason to do it, don't fight the Auto Configuration magic of Spring Boot.